Need to replace a code in exe - how patching a batch of instructions via Ghidra can be done?
I have a Ghidra project with an imported binary file (for x86 32 bit processor). I need to change a function in it.
I`ve created a new function  code assembly. In listing it is 100 code lines - Modifying the code by replacing each original instruction via patch instruction (line by line) looks long and wired . I`ve tried to make a patch for all instructions - but looks that this option doesn`t exist! Also I thought about  exporting the current file (listing) and editing it (in text format)
I am not sure how to do that?
can you advice
